# Composer works on console but not within a script

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

This is really mysterious for me.. This lines are working, entered manually in a console:

```
cd /var/www/html/api
sudo composer install
sudo composer update
mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "DROP DATABASE laravel"
mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "CREATE DATABASE laravel CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed --class DatabaseSeeder
```

But within a script, it is not working, and crashes CD command, even if I use sudo or try it as admin...

Any hint?

Comment: what is the error message on crash - can you confirm `/var/www/html/api` exists at the time the script runs ? you can just do `ls -lR /var/www` to check content at this time

Answer (score 0):

Sudo won't work with cd. You should check permission for user that executes your script.

Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291666/why-doesnt-sudo-cd-var-named-work) as an example.